# Duvidas com a utilização do IF / ELSE em C

Tags: java, if, else

Quando eu executo este código e digito o sexo=M ou =F, todas as condições são executadas conforme esperado. Já quando eu digito o sexo=m ou =f, apenas a primeira condição é atendida, independente do valor da idade.

Alguém pode me explicar direito a utilização e a estrutura dos **IF / ELSE** ?

```
int main()
{
    float salB, idade, medica;
    char sexo;

    printf("           PROGRAMA 2");
    printf("\n_________________________________");

    printf("\n\n Informe o sexo do funcionario, digite M para masculino ou F para feminino: ");
    scanf("%c",&sexo);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n Digite o valor do salario bruto: ");
    scanf("%f",&salB);
    printf("\n Digite a idade: ");
    scanf("%f",&idade);

    if (sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M' && idade < 20)
    {
        medica = (salB*5)/100;
        printf("\n O funcionario pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
    }
    else if (sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M' && idade >= 21 && idade < 40)
    {
        medica = (salB*7)/100;
        printf("\n O funcionario pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
    }
    else if (sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M' && idade > 40)
    {
        medica = (salB*10)/100;
        printf("\n O funcionario pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
    }
    else if (sexo == 'f' || sexo == 'F' && idade < 20)
    {
        medica = (salB*2)/100;
        printf("\n A funcionaria pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
    }
    else if (sexo == 'f' || sexo == 'F' && idade >= 21 && idade < 40)
    {
        medica = (salB*5)/100;
        printf("\n A funcionaria pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
    }
    else if (sexo == 'f' || sexo == 'F' && idade > 40)
    {
        medica = (salB*7)/100;
        printf("\n A funcionaria pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Sexo invalido, tente novamente.");
        system("pause > null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tenho alguns pontos que queria te ajudar além da resposta, bom o seu controle de idade não controla quando a idade é 20 ou 40 e nem quando é negativa ( pois n existe idade negativa).

Eu reescrevi o código de forma que a logica ficasse mais clara, gerenciando primeiro o sexo e depois a idade( não mudei a logica da idade = 20 ou = 40):

```
int main()
{
    float salB, idade, medica;
    char sexo;

    printf("           PROGRAMA 2");
    printf("\n_________________________________");

    printf("\n\n Informe o sexo do funcionario, digite M para masculino ou F para feminino: ");
    scanf("%c",&sexo);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n Digite o valor do salario bruto: ");
    scanf("%f",&salB);
    printf("\n Digite a idade: ");
    scanf("%f",&idade);
    // controle para homens
    if (sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M')
    { 
        if(idade < 20){
            medica = (salB*5)/100;
            printf("\n O funcionario pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
        }
        else if(idade >= 21 && idade < 40){
            medica = (salB*7)/100;
            printf("\n O funcionario pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
        }
        else if(idade > 40){
            medica = (salB*10)/100;
            printf("\n O funcionario pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
        }
    }
    // controle para mulheres
    else if(sexo == 'f' || sexo == 'F'){
        if(idade < 20){
            medica = (salB*2)/100;
            printf("\n A funcionaria pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
        }
        else if(idade >= 21 && idade < 40){
            medica = (salB*5)/100;
            printf("\n A funcionaria pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
        }
        else if(idade > 40){
            medica = (salB*7)/100;
            printf("\n A funcionaria pagara R$%.2f de assistencia medica.",medica);
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("\n Sexo invalido, tente novamente.");
    }
        system("pause > null");
}
```

Tem também uma questão de performance, o seu código faz um monte de controle, digo, primeiro se é mulher e idade menor que 20, depois se é mulher e idade entre um período de idade, depois se e mulher e idade maior que quarenta...
Bom assim se faz muito controle e perde um pouco de performance.

O que eu fiz foi, faz um controle pra ver o sexo, e depois faz o controle para ver a idade, na pior dar hipóteses o meu código faz 4 controles. O seu na pior das hipóteses faz 6. Sei que é um ganho pequeno, mas ganho é sempre ganho.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ajudou sim, e muito. Obrigado pelas dicas !

Answer (score 1):

Você tem duas opções, uma seria fazer um ToUpper e comparar apenas com 'M' ao invés de m ou M

a segunda opção é a seguinte:

```
 if ((sexo == 'm' || sexo == 'M') && idade < 20)
```

Ficaria da seguinte forma: se o sexo for m OU M, E a idade < 20
Os parênteses são muito importantes para você isolar aquela condição.

Comment: Esse esquema do ToUpper eu ainda não conhecia, muito bom, irei estudar mais sobre ele. Tambem não sabia que tem que usar mais de 1 parentese nas condiçoes para isolar cada situação. Valeu Thiago!